# Limit of a sequence that diverges

Tags: calculus, limits

For the following sequence:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (ln (n))^{\sqrt{n}}$

I'm not sure if it's sufficient to show that it is equal to:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {\sqrt{n}}(ln(n))$

and then this diverges.

Have I done anything wrong? If so, what is the correct method to go about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Note that $\ln(n^{\sqrt{n}})=\sqrt{n}(\ln (n))$, but $(\ln(n))^{\sqrt{n}}\neq\sqrt{n}(\ln (n))$ in general.

Comment: Oh I see, in that case would you know how I could go about solving the problem?

Comment: For $n>3$ it is obvious that $(\ln n)^{\sqrt{n}}>\ln n$, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty }(\ln(n))^{\sqrt{n}}\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln n=+\infty.$

Comment: What method are you using? Comparison? I thought comparison could only be used for series?

Comment: Comparison also works for limit of sequences or functions if the limits are infinity.